# Run a function before hitting return. iOS, Swift,

Tags: ios, swift, return, guard

Is there a way to run a function if a guard statment is not met before it gets to return?

```
guard let detectedRectangle = observations.first else { 

  functionToRun(completion: { (complete) in 

      print("Tony GOT TO RETURN"); return }
    })
```

The above code makes me put the return outside of the complete in part.

```
guard let detectedRectangle = observations.first else { 

  functionToRun(completion: { (complete) in 


    })

print("Tony GOT TO RETURN"); return }
```

I have set 3 print statements in the function to run at certain points and it gets to 2 of them before hiting the return print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `functionToRun` if the func, that contains `guard` statement, has same return type as `functionToRun`. Example:

```
func guardHolder() { // guardHolder returns Void
    guard let detectedRectangle = observations.first else {
        // so, if functionToRun also returns Void type, we can return this func
        return functionToRun { _ in print("Tony GOT TO RETURN") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exelent This was whatIi needed, Thank you for your explination on this now i know a little more.